# R download.file not returning all rows

Tags: r

I have a .gz zip file on a network drive. it contains a .cax file

I

```
url<- "file:///B:/me/test.gz"
file <- tempfile()
download.file(url,file)
file
g<-gzfile(description=temp, open = "r",encoding = getOption("encoding"),compression = 6)
g
lines<-readLines(g,skipNul= TRUE)
lines
```

g shows

```
> g
description       class        mode        text      opened    can read   can write 
  "test.gz"    "gzfile"         "r"      "text"    "opened"       "yes"        "no"
```

so the connection is open and when I get back data in lines I get back 14 lines but there are 35k lines in the data.

Any idea why only 14 of 35k rows are returning?

I also get a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In readLines(g, skipNul = TRUE) :
  seek on a gzfile connection returned an internal error
```

what is weird is that when i save the .zip file to my dektop and run this code I get the same warning message and all 35k lines of data.

any idea?

Comment: .gz files are not .zip files. And `readLines` is not designed to bring in either version of compressed file. It's designed for files that are delimited by carriage returns.

Comment: They are similar correct?  Any ideas why only 14 rows return?

Comment: Maybe you only had 14 "carriage return" characters in the compressed file?

Comment: Well when I look at "lines" it shows the same first 14 rows as I see when I unzip from my desktop. For some reason the download.file is only downloading 14 rows not the entire 35k rows

Comment: Maybe a ctrl-Z character is in there?

Comment: the download.file funcation adds the CTRL+Z character? Do you know what it looks like?

Comment: Isn't that the end-of-file character in some OSes?

Comment: Try opening the gzfile with mode "rb" (i.e., read a binary file)?

Comment: @Marting when I did open = "rb" I still get 15 rows. The problems is with the download.file function because I can go to the temporary file returned from download.file and use gzfile and it has 14 rows. It I do not use download.file and just save the .gz file to my desktop and then use gzfile to open I get 35k rows

Comment: Can you post what a `.cax` file looks like? If it isn't truly a text file then `readLines()` is not what you want. `readBin()` will read binary files, though I'm not certain what you intend to do with the file once you read it; I can't find a good definition of the cax file format.